# WPF - Bind DataGridTextColumn from id -> child table field

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid that is populated by an sql table.  One of the fields is an id related (one-to-many) to another table within the database.  When i show this field in the database, i would like to show it as a TextBlock/DataGridTextColumn that references a name field in the child table.  The child table is preloaded within a view model as the MainWindow's DataContext.

I have been looking into property indexers to attempt to do this, but it seems the index cannot be variable, such as;

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier name" Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Suppliers[{Binding SupplierID}].SupplierName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Am i trying to do the wrong thing here? Should I instead be using a Converter? Or, should I be simply binding the datagrid to an SQL View that contains both the id and the name field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a MultiBinding with a converter. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property/4100979#4100979) and in your case pass in 'Suppliers' and 'SupplierID' to the MultiValueConverter.

Comment: thanks colin, this worked however the performance hit was considerable.  It would seem it is better to get SQL to return a view with the supplier name included.

Comment: actually, i take that back, my performance issues were related to something else, this works a treat! :)