# Binding from image array in XAML

Tags: xaml, binding

In XAML I'v got

```
<Image x:Name="optionImage1" Source="{Binding OptionsImage}"/>
```

OptionsImage is returning ImageSource[] -array.

How can I bind to specific point of array, ie {Binding OptionsImage=[1]}

As you can see from the question I'm total new on XAML and "answers for dummies" are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using WPF or Silverlight.

You are nearly there. [Use this syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx).

```
<Image x:Name="optionImage1" Source="{Binding OptionsImage[1]}"/>
```

See also this question: [Binding in WPF to element of array specified by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property)

Comment: Thanks a lot! There was another problem which was actually the main problem (stupid null reference :-)). Well it's working now after hours of "thinking"..