# WPF- Create a list of Visibilities

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visibility

In this moment, I'm working with WPF and MVVM. I have in a UniformGrid with 30 buttons, each one with specific DynamicResource and specific Content (Text). I need to manage the visibility for each button, but I don't want to do a variable for each button.

I'm thinking in create a list of Visibilities  and Binding this list. But I don't want to lose the UniformGrid, only I want binding each element of list in different button.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100979/2465182. Would this work if you bound each button to an element in your Visibilities list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to create ExpandObject.

I created a ExpandObject as Dictonary

```
 var visibilitiesAsDictionary  = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
```

Then I add all variables, in string I put the name of variable and the Object his value.

```
visibilitiesAsDictionary.Add("Item1", Visibility.Visible);
visibilitiesAsDictionary.Add("Item2", Visibility.Visible);
```

After I create Dynamic variable

```
private dynamic _visibilities;
public dynamic Visibilities
    {
        get { return _visibilities; }
        set { _visibilities = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Visibilities"); }
    }
```

Then,

```
Visibilities = visibilitiesAsDictionary
```

And in Xaml I bind the property

```
<Button Command="{Binding Item1Command}" Visibility="{Binding Visibilities.Item1}">
<Button Command="{Binding Item2Command}" Visibility="{Binding Visibilities.Item2}">
```

So, when I initialize Dictionary, doesn't matter in that order I do it, because the property will be bind for a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind directly to an item in a list by specifying the index.

```
<Button Content="Button 1" Visibility="{Binding Visibilities[0]}" />
<Button Content="Button 2" Visibility="{Binding Visibilities[1]}" />
<Button Content="Button 3" Visibility="{Binding Visibilities[2]}" />
```

With Visibilities defined as such in the ViewModel

```
Visibilities = new List<Visibility>()
{ Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Collapsed, Visibility.Visible};
```

You just need to make sure to raise a PropertyChanged event whenever you change a value in the list so that the controls will notice the change.

```
var handler = PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visibilities"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** This is insane, please don't try it.

---

This is not for the faint of heart, but one possibility is to use the runtime type system to implement custom properties.  You can tailor a custom type to expose the properties you want, while still maintaining a list of visibilities internally.  Using simple properties like this:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Visibilities.V1}" />
<Button Visibility="{Binding Visibilities.V2}" />
```

You would then want your "Visibilities" object to implement a class that implements "ICustomTypeProvider", wrapping the appropriate data (an array of `Visibility`).  It should also expose an indexer for the underlying values, and the setter should raise "PropertyChanged":

```
public class VisibilitiesClass : ICustomTypeProvider, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Visibility[] Visibilities { get; private set; };

    public VisibilitiesClass(int count) 
    {
        Visibilities = new Visibility[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            Visibilities[i] = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public Type GetCustomType()
    {
        return new VisibilitiesType(Visibilities.Length);
    }

    public Visibility this[int index]
    {
        get { return Visibilities[index]; }
        set
        {
            Visibilities[index] = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("V" + index);
        }
    }
}
```

The `VisibilitiesType` referenced above should extend `Type`, and will return the property list as needed ("V1", "V2", ..., "Vn"):

```
public class VisibilitiesType : Type
{
    private int _count;

    public VisibilitiesType(int count)
    {
        _count = count;
    }

    public override PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, _count).Select(i => new VisibilityProperty(i)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And finally the "VisibilityProperty" should extend "PropertyInfo", and return the appropriate value from the host object:

```
public class VisibilityProperty : PropertyInfo
{
    private int _index;

    public VisibilityProperty(int index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "V" + _index; }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var host = obj as VisibilitiesClass;
        return host[_index];
    }
}
```

Note that the above implementation is very ellided -- there are a ton of virtual methods for both "Type" and "PropertyInfo", some of which you may need to override.

Comment: Yep ... This is not for the faint of heart :) (we should have a faint heart badge in SO ...)