# WPF twoway binding of array elements

Tags: wpf, multibinding

I have an array of values representing columns widths. I am trying to bind those values within a grid such that the displayed column widths match the array. The problem is, I can't use explicit indexing (e.g. [0], [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property)) since the number of columns will change dynamically. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property) question which suggests using a MultiBinding to let me use dynamic indexing. This gives me the following code when a column is added:

```
while (mGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count < maxColCount)
{
    ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
    int newIdx = mGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
    if(ColumnWidths.Count > newIdx)
    {
        if(ColumnWidths[newIdx].Value < 0)
            ColumnWidths[newIdx] = DefaultColumnWidth;

        MultiBinding bind = new MultiBinding();
        bind.Converter = mHeightWidthConverter;
        bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("ColumnWidths"));
        bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding { Source = newIdx });
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        colDef.SetBinding(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, bind);
    }
    else
        colDef.Width= DefaultColumnWidth;
    mGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
}
```

with the converter:

```
public class HeightWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values == null || values.Length < 2)
            return null;

        ObservableCollection<GridLength> array = values[0] as ObservableCollection<GridLength>;
        int index = (int)values[1];
        if(array.Count > index)
            return array[index];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works well for oneway binding but I need twoway binding. Looking at the ConvertBack function of the convert, I can't figure out how to get that to assign "value" to the correct element of the original array.

Suggestions?

Comment: how about this: `object[] originalValues` as a property on your Converter and then when you convert back return originalValues. remember though to add the item to the originalValues when you convert them. I hope I'm clear enough HTH.

Comment: I thought about that but it seemed a bit fragile. If the data source changes then I have to explicitly update the convert myself.

Comment: what values do you expect when it convert back? Index is lost as you did not return the index when you convert. In short what is the expected behavior for convert back?

Comment: It's not that ConvertBack is behaving unexpectedly, it just doesn't do what I want. Ideally, I would be able to do something like array[index] = value. Clearly, I need a change in mindset but I'm not sure where to start.