# Binding in XAML AND C# to get the elements of Array in Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was trying to implement Buttons in `XAML` in which the `Content` of the button has to come from an `array` from my `C#` code.

This is part of my `C#` code which has an integer array `[,] arr`

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    public int [,] arr;  //This array gets values from another C# file in the Main method

    private void Click_Me1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button obj = (Button)sender;
        //some code
    }

    private void Click_Me2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button obj = (Button)sender;
        // some code
    }
}
```

This is part of my XAML code where I have 2 buttons-

```
<Button x:Name="Click_Me1" 
    Content="4" 
    Click="Start"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="123,45,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />

<Button x:Name="Click_Me2" 
    Content="5" 
    Click="Start"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="123,45,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

In these Buttons I want the contents from the array `arr` of my `C#` code.I know `XAML` is declarative language so we cannot get the values of array directly. So how can I use `binding` in this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding in WPF to element of array specified by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property)

Comment: The problem occuring in this is that I get the array updated in the `Main` method only,so I cannot use the `constructor` for `binding` as there is array is null error then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MVVM pattern. 
XAML code:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonContents}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding }"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

ViewModel code:

```
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ButtonContents = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            ButtonContents.Add("3");
            ButtonContents.Add("4");
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ButtonContents { get; set; }
    }
```