# XAML Binding index operator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to bind the value inside a [] operator from a different data context that the one containing the array itself?

I manage to get the correct index within the element I would like to bind with this binding:

```
Binding DataContext.INDEX_ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UCIndexByClientKeyMeasure}}
```

Where INDEX_ID gives me the correct integer

but I can't get this index works inside another binding. I tried:

```
Binding .[{Binding  DataContext.INDEX_ID,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UCIndexByClientKeyMeasure}}}]
```

When I passed a satic value such as:

```
Binding .[10]
```

Then it works.

Thanks

Comment: Would say duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property

Answer (score 0):

MultiBinding indeed...thanks

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource clientIndexConverter}"
              StringFormat="N2">
    <Binding Path="DataContext.INDEX_ID"
             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UCIndexByClientKeyMeasure}}" />
    <Binding Path="." />
</MultiBinding>
```